# stringbyappendingstring different size and font types

Tags: ios, nsstring, uifont

I have a NSString that is a letter and another that is their signature. I need to combine both into a single string for display but the signature needs to display in a different font and size.  Yes, both fonts and sizes are working on their own.

Right now I have it as follows:

```
NSString *letter;
NSString *signOff;

_paragraph.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BeinetCondensed" size:14];
_signature.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AnnoyingKettle" size:18];

letter = [_paragraph text];
signOff = [_signature text];

NSString *completedLetter = [letter stringByAppendingString:signOff];
```

completedLetter displays as the same size and font type.

Answer (score 1):

You're playing in the wrong ball park - looking in the wrong place - barking up the wrong tree - using the wrong class.

`text` and NSString and `stringByAppendingString` have *no* size or font information. The fonts of `_paragraph` and `_signature` are utterly irrelevant; they are merely ways in which those views display strings that of themselves lack any font at all. Thus, when you combine strings that have no fonts, you still wind up with a string that has no font.

If you want to work with strings that *do* have size and font information, you need to start working with NSAttributedString (and `attributedText`).

This is a single NSAttributedString:

[image]

Comment: And here's the part of my book that teaches you how to do it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_attributed_strings

Comment: I am displaying the end result in a UITextView and I understand it doesn't support NSAttributedString.  Am I correct?

Comment: You're correct if you're using iOS 5 or before. Otherwise, no, you're not correct.

Comment: Good to know!  I will try the attributed string and thank you. Checking your link and hopefully marking this answer correct

Answer (score 0):

there is a old method,may be useful;

```
self.title = @"For iOS 6 & later";  
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Using NSAttributed String"];  
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];  
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(6,12)];  
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(19,6)];  
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldItalicMT" size:30.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];  
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:30.0] range:NSMakeRange(6, 12)];  
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier-BoldOblique" size:30.0] range:NSMakeRange(19, 6)];  
attrLabel.attributedText = str;
```

Comment: I have seen this example but don't always know the size of the signature and can't use NSMakeRange.  It will always be a different size.